# Handling different view model states in MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I’m using the MVVM pattern for my metro app.  On my main page, the user presses a button and the app gets the current location of the user.

The process of getting the user’s location is asynchronous and I want the UI to change, so the button will be disabled and an indeterminate progress bar will display until the co-ordinates are returned.

What is the best way to manage this according to MVVM?  Having a custom visual state?  I notice that there are ApplicationViewStates and CommonStates, is it possible to add your own custom ones?
How would you do this?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're handling updating the view for the progress bar, but can't you create the "Progress" property as a nullable type and if the Progress is null, show the indeterminate progress bar and disable the button?

Comment: Sure, but I'm interested in whether people would generally define some custom visual states like "normal", "findinglocation" and then transition between those states with a storyboard..  Or I suppose bind directly to properties on the view model and use value converters. E.g., bool to visibility. Thx

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like:

viewModel:

```
private async void CommandExecution()
{
    IsAwaitingResponse=true;
    var response = await _myService.DoNetworkCall()
    IsAwaitingResponse=false;
}
```

If you're using one of the microsoft templates you should have a BooleanToVisibilityConverter sitting in your "Common" folder.  You use it like so:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:key="booleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>
"..."
<ProgressBar Visibility={Binding IsAwaitingResponse,Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" IsIndeterminate="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

My xaml experience is with WPF and Silverlight, but I hope this suggestion works for a Metro app.  You can bind the button's IsEnabled property and the progress bar's visibility property to a boolean property (maybe call it IsCurrentLocationComplete) on your view-model.  You'll change this property's value when the async method is complete and your view will be updated.  Setting the Button's property is straight forward, but you'll need a value converter (IValueConverter) for the progress bar's visibility one.